# Is the darts minigame in the Final Fantasy VII Remake based on a real variant of darts?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

[image: Darts in Final Fantasy VII Remake (image credit: Video Games Blogger)]

There's a darts minigame in the recently-released Final Fantasy VII Remake, but I've noticed that it doesn't follow the usual rules. There are two things I've spotted which differentiate it from standard darts rules:

- The green ring around the bullseye awards 50 points, not 25;
- The player can end on a single, double or triple, not just a double.

There is a minor reward given to players who beat Wedge's 301 score of 8 darts, meaning the player has to land at least 3 triples and 3 doubles, 4 triples and 1 double, or 6 bullseyes to achieve this, so I don't believe this was done to make it easier for the player.

Is there a real variant of darts which follows this ruleset?

Answer (score 3):

301 is a valid variation of darts.

Straight-out, where you can finish on anything (as long as you don't go below 0 score), is a valid variation too.

I have never known anyone to play 50 points for outer bull though.

Having said that, the beauty of darts is you can play any rules you want as long as all players agree.

To be specific though, I dont believe there is a commonly played variant (with a specific name) that meets all this criteria. Closest would be "301 straight-out".